# How to removed READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission from my app?

Tags: android, android-permissions

When I upload my app to the google store (aab file), I can see that additional permissions were added to the app :

***Photos/Media/Files-** -read the contents of your USB storage -modify or delete the contents of your USB storage

***Storage-** -read the contents of your USB storage -modify or delete the contents of your USB storage

android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

I do need to save texture images on the phone gallery so I agree with the "write permission"
But I don't need to READ. 
I don't see that I ask for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in any manifest so where does this request come from?

I even added a remove command to remove this permission if was added, and in the final manifest I don't see READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but it still shows in the end in the store. 
When my users play the game it asks them if they agree to allow my app to get access to their albums :\

Comment: are you using any 3rd-party libraries? They might be have declared those permissions in their respective AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I searched in all the manifest files and even added a remove command     <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: If you ask for write you get read too.